# NIC's Identity in the Redhat change after replacing the NIC

Tags: networking, ip, redhat, nic

--

Hi,everybody.

My server runs Redhat enterprise linux 6.3. And i config a stable IP address for my machine by
modifying the config file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`.

We can see that the NIC's identity is "eth0". We have 4 NICs, so they are eth0, eth1,eth2, eth3.

For some reasons, i replaced those NICs with new ones. Here comes the problem.

After restarting system, the NICs' identity changed into eth4, eth5, eth6, eth7 automatically. And  the configuration file of stable IP address names "***-eth0". So it can't use the config file automatically now.

How to change them back into eth0, eth1, eth2, eth3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by modifying "/etc/udev/rules.d/zNN_persistent-net.rules".